# FreeBSD 10: NFS unable to export folder

Tags: freebsd, nfs, zfs

I am unable to export a folder using NFS.

/etc/exports

```
/storage/test -maproot=nobody client
/storage/test1 -ro -maproot=nobody client
/storage/test2 -ro -maproot=nobody client
```

The first folder test is working fine, the other 2 i get this error:

```
Jul 18 11:10:40 server mountd[6499]: bad exports list line /storage/test1 -ro -maproot
Jul 18 11:10:41 server mountd[6499]: can't change attributes for /storage/test1: Invalid radix node head, rn: 0 0xfffff80092530100
```

The filesystem is ZFS RAID Z2.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot generate multiple mounts on the same filesystem. [LINK](http://www.m.opensubscriber.com/message/freebsd-stable@freebsd.org/17044959.html)

When using this export:

```
/storage/test /storage/test1 /storage/test2 -maproot=nobody client
```

This works, but one is unable to specify specific permissions for the folders....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "-alldirs" parameter:

```
/storage -alldirs -maproot=nobody client
```